# Regular Expression match country?

Tags: php, regex

i would like a regular expression that checks input text for validity with with following:

may contain lowercase
may contain upper case
may contain space
may not contain anything else.

i want to use this inside my php code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean only the basic latin alphabet and only literal spaces (not tabs etc.):

`/^[a-zA-Z ]*\z/`

Comment: +1 works great, what is *\z.. may you please divide and explain it.

Comment: There is no need to check the entire string, this will search an entire input even if the first character is invalid.

Comment: @TDsii `*` means 0 or more of the preceding character, `\z` is the end of the subject string - you often see `$` used for this but `$` allows a trailing newline.

Comment: @Jacob that's a good point but unlikely to be an issue if it's such a short string ;) I agree with Andrew & Rob too - a dropdown would be far more user friendly and less error prone.

Comment: @Jacob: it won't check the whole string. If the first character is invalid, the backtracker will start again at the previous partial match but wont be able to continue. It will fail almost immediately after encountering an invalid character, and will never check the following character.

Comment: @Jacob: the opposite of jb's problem? That little carat is too easy to misread.

Comment: @Long Ears I want ()/ // to be included also so what will I do? I want country Name Alaska (Atalanta) Plz help me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how localized you want this but it's not so much a job for a regex. Taking a [list of known sovereign states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states) and making a lookup table is going to be your best bet.

Comment: or better yet, provide a drop down list

Comment: @Rob: Ok, yeah, I might have over engineered that one a bit.

Comment: Some ammunition for this argument: 'Guinea-Bissau' and 'Côte d'Ivoire' both would fail the simplistic regex. Furthermore using a dropdown allows you to normalize to ISO codes (ISO code as value, name as content.)

Comment: we're all guilty of that at least twice a day.